# image get from binary and store in folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I Have created a website where image upload functionality will be provide.
i done the insert image in binary format and also Edit and delete will be done but now the requirement will be change.

first i put insert logic here.

```
  <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="left" class="LabelFont">Logo :
                            </td>
                            <td width="74%" valign="top" align="left">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="flLogo" runat="server"/> 

                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

**and in code behind...**

```
If (flLogo.HasFile.ToString()) Then
                Dim File As HttpPostedFile = flLogo.PostedFile
                imgByte = New Byte(File.ContentLength - 1) {}
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength)
```

SO in imagebyte i get the binary image after that i insert in in database ...

> NOW MY Question Start. my boss ask me that get image from binary and
>   store in folder with max  Cust_id.

**So How to save image in folder from binary image ?**

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 2):

You can save the image directly:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(flLogo.PostedFile.InputStream)
bmp.Save(yourPath)
```